# Defining NAOqi ALProxy Proxies

Tags: python-2.7, nao-robot

I have written a python script for the NAO Robot so that it can take a photo. I have written the import `from naoqi import ALProxy` and wrote out the a try statement as follows:

```
try:
    postureProxy = ALProxy("ALRobotPosture", ip, port)
    motionProxy = ALProxy("ALMotion", ip, port)
    speechProxy = ALProxy("ALTextToSpeech", ip, port)
    anspeechProxy = ALProxy("ALAnimatedSpeech", ip, port)
    sprecogProxy = ALProxy("ALSpeechRecognition", ip, port)
    memoryProxy = ALProxy("ALMemory", ip, port)
    photoCaptureProxy = ALProxy("ALPhotoCapture", ip, port)
```

Later in my script, I have the following:

```
sprecogProxy.setLanguage("English")
```

I get an error saying:

> NameError: name 'sprecogProxy' is not defined
>   Also, later in my code I refer to the speech Proxy as I say :

```
speechProxy.say("Place the object in the view")
```

I get the same error. Earlier my program was working correctly and all of a sudden I am getting this error. Is there anything that can be done to mitigate this program so that this script can run consistently? 
Please let me know if there is a need for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an error in your Python, like you're trying to use a variable that was never created (for example one of your ALProxy objects raised an exception at creation, so it never reached the part where it creates sprecogProxy).